# Category NSMutableDictionary/NSDictionary should return NSMutableDictionary/NSDictionary Depending of the caller class

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, categories, nsmutabledictionary, nserror

I was busy with this for some hours, but see no head or tail.

How should I create an `NS(Mutable)Dictionary` category that I can let return the same class as the sending method class.

Sample

```
+(NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithAdditions:path error:(NSError**)error;

NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithAdditions:path error:&error];
```

should return an `NSDictionary`.

AND

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryWithAdditions:path error:(NSError**)error;

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithAdditions:path error:&error];
```

should return an NSMutableDictionary.

I dont want to return an `id`, to avoid any possible warning etc.

Suggestions how I should create this in one category with error management?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create two different methods (e.g. `dictionaryWithAdditions:` and `mutableDictionaryWithAdditions:`) or return `id` (I would suggest the latter). The type system doesn't allow us to say "NSDictionary if the receiver is statically typed as NSDictionary, NSMutableDictionary if the receiver is statically typed as NSMutableDictionary, and error otherwise".

Answer (score 0):

What warnings would you get when returning `id`? That's what the standard `init` method does anyway.

Your method would probably look something like:

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithAdditions:path error:(NSError**)error;
{
     id dictionary = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];

     // ... do something

     return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to use things like [ class self] to get the current class. I will stick too (id).